# ssl certificate issue (ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have reissue my domain Certificate , then I've update certificate and key files for my servers it works only on one of them and get ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR problem for others although all these servers use subdomains of the same domain . I have no idea where to look and how to trubleshooting this problem .
My question is : what would make ssl certificate work on one server and not work to another Although two servers use subdomains of same domain?
would you help me please ..

nginx configuration

```
server {
    #listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    

    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate    /etc/nginx/sites-available/ssl/mycert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/sites-available/ssl/mykey.key;
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X- 
        Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80  ;
        server_name mydomain;
        return 301 https://mydomain$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: It is likely a misconfiguration. Only, there are no details known about the configuration in the first place so no help is possible here. Check the logs of the unknown server for errors.

Comment: thanks for reply , I have add my nginx config to the post and this is the same config file in two servers , and for logs of the unknown server for errors : nothing is appear in log file

Comment: A certificate does not depend on a specific server. If the configs on both systems are exactly the same it has to be something outside these configs, like certificate not stored at the correct place, wrong permissions or mismatch between certificate and key - but in this cases errors should be found in the logs. In which logs did you look?

Comment: yes as you said if the problem is mismatch between certificate and key or incorrect place for certificate stored or something like that it must be appear during restart nginx  in nginx error logs file (where I have look) , but this not happen (nginx restart normally and no error appear in log file) . what would be the reason of this problem ??